# Chrome stretches images set by CSS aspect-ratio 1/1

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I don’t have the width or height for the image to add as an attribute so setting *aspect ratio* is the solution I’m seeking.

The problem is that Chrome stretches the image if the image width is greater than the container. However, the image looks fine in Firefox.

```css
body {
    max-width: 400px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1640113163135-dd802f7e5961?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60'>

<img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1640127444725-3926729d6ebd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=963&q=80'>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ahmadajmi/full/yLzzqVo

I tried to play around `object-fit: scale-down;` but ended up with white space before and after the image.

Firefox view:

[image]

Chrome view:

[image]

Any suggestions for a Chrome fix?

Comment: Seems like [Chrome is the one doing this correctly](https://web.dev/aspect-ratio/). Firefox does it in the nightly build. Why would you expect a 1:1 aspect ratio to not be square?

Comment: Why are you setting aspect-ratio to start with? your first sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to me

Comment: The issue clearly isn't the image. The local demo I added showed what you describe perfectly. Anyway, I think you misunderstand what aspect ratio is meant to do. What you see in Chrome is _correct_. It's Firefox that's not fully supporting it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to prevent layout shift. Adding aspect ratio I think would prevent that as I don’t have access to the image width and height.

Comment: you will have layout shift since you don't know the real aspect-ratio. So either you force the ratio to something fixed (the behavior of chrome) or you have the behavior of firefox with a layout shift because the ratio will not be the one you defined.

Comment: @isherwood that makes more sense now.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think I need to look into other solutions as aspect ratio seems not the right fix. Or may use another ratio value (16 / 9) for example combined with object-fit.